# How to get Postgres C Function's Object file parameter from Catalog tables?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a Postgres C Function as below in the Postgres DB

```
  CREATE FUNCTION uuid_generate_v4() RETURNS uuid
  LANGUAGE c STRICT
  AS '$libdir/uuid-ossp', 'uuid_generate_v4';
```

I could get the link symbol from the below query

```
select r.external_name as linkSymbol from information_schema.routines r
where r.specific_schema = 'public' and r.routine_name = 'uuid_generate_v4'
```

But I could not find out a option to get Object File value from information_schema...
Is there some other options through which i can get the Object file value... ?

Thanks in advance,

Ravi

Comment: I could get the Object file value by using the below query,  select probin from pg_proc p join pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace 
where n.nspname = 'public' and p.proname = 'uuid_generate'

Comment: Would you mind posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As the OP already found out the query is:

```
select probin 
  from pg_proc p 
  join pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace 
 where n.nspname = 'public' and p.proname = 'uuid_generate'
```

I figured on top of a prettier representation, it would be worth mentioning that in this case the prosrc column points to the entry point symbol in the object file, if you ever need it.